# Slow synch of files form iPad to webserver?

Tags: iphone, ipad

I'm building a recording iPad application that will take some moderately large recordings on the iPad (5-10 minutes of full audio roughly 5-10Megabytes in size.)  How can I synch such large files to my web server for use?  I want the synching to occur asynchronously in the background.  Is there an existing library/utility to synch files in the Megabyte range from an iPhone/iPad to a server in small chunks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`ASIHTTPRequest`](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) to make asynchronous web requests, i.e. run your requests in a background thread.